# Swift Call ViewController after url loading finishes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm building an App that does exactly the following:
The user logins with his username and password, after the login I retrieve some data from the website through HTML Parsing.
These Data I want to pass them to the other ViewController which is a Table View Controller to show the data in the cells there.

I connected the Login button to the other ViewController by a seague, but can't keep it waiting till the Data are available.

How can I do this?

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
    sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "supplierDetails" {
    let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController
    as SupplierDetails

    detailViewController.Data = Data


    }
}

func PostRequest() {

    self.spinner.hidden = false
    self.spinner.startAnimating()

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://example.com/login.aspx")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "something"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            println("error=\(error)")
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.spinner.stopAnimating()
                self.spinner.hidden = true
            });

            return
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.spinner.stopAnimating()
            self.spinner.hidden = true
            self.Data = parseHTML.getContent(data)
            self.transition()
            });
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the segue from the button. When you're ready to move to the other view controller, call the segue using `performSegueWithIdentifier(_:sender:)`.

Comment: I've added self.performSegueWithIdentifier("supplierDetails", sender: self), but the app now crashes and gives "thread 1: EXC_Breakpoint(code=EXC_i386_bpt" Error :/